# Is it possible for a logic system to contradict itself?

Tags: logic

Is it possible for a logic system to contradict itself? If so, what are the ones that don't contradict themselves and what are the ones that contradict themselves? And how do you prove or determine that a logic system contradict itself and what logic system do you use to determine that, do you have to use the same logic itself onto itself or a different logic system onto that logic system?

Comment: Proof theory proposes once a deductive system has the so-called *subformula property* from [cut elimination theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem#Cut_elimination) then it must be consistent, thus it's very easy to prove the consistency of sequent calculus of classic logic (aka LK) as compared to other Hilbert/ND systems via the usual soundness theorem. However, it's very hard and still debated for consistency of most axiomatic formal systems embedding PA, Gentzen famously had to resort to consistency of Skolem's PRA via transfinite induction up to ε0 to "prove" PA's...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, contradictory logical systems are easy to build:

- Logical connectives: AND, NOT
- Axiom 1: A
- Axiom 2: NOT(A)
- Rule of inference: Conjunction (p,q \vdash p AND q)

We may infer A AND NOT(A) which is a contradiction.

These systems are not problematic, just not applicable to any interesting context.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for a logic system to contradict itself?

By definition, strictly speaking, you don't contradict yourself if you are logical.

However, one may choose to say something illogical for logical reasons. For example, if you don't want to die, it is logical to say something illogical if this is what it takes to save your own life. So, saying something illogical does not imply that you are illogical yourself.

In other words, words are cheap and people say whatever they please. You also draw the inferences you like from what people say or do, but then you may be wrong.

For essentially the same reasons, strictly speaking, a logical system cannot contradict itself. However, people do what they like and it is a fact you can call "logical system" something which contradicts itself and therefore is not a logical system. In other words, "logical system" is only a label and one which may not mean that the system is logical, and usually doesn't.

So, a logical system cannot contradict itself but it is possible that something called "logical system" does.

> If so, what are the ones that don't contradict themselves and what are the ones that contradict themselves?

Any system which has the law of contradiction as an axiom and either admits the principle of explosion, or the principle of ex falso quodlibet, or the principle of ex contradictione quodlibet, can easily produce mutually contradictory sentences, and therefore contradict itself.

> And how do you prove or determine that a logic system contradict itself.

> and what logic system do you use to determine that, do you have to use the same logic itself onto itself or a different logic system onto that logic system?

If you use two logical systems, say, S₁ and S₂, to arrive somehow at one conclusion, then your system is the conjunction of S₁ and S₂, not S₁ and not S₂ on their own. This can work if the two systems are consistent and not contradictory. That being said, reasonable people don't do that.

So, strictly speaking, a system that contradicts itself has first to admit the law of contradiction as axiomatic, and then be able to somehow produce contradictory results. For example, any system that admits the principle of explosion can produce contradictory results.

Comment: You have this completely backwards. It is systems that *don't* have explosion that are able to accommodate contradictions. For example, the logic of paradox is a dialethic logic which allows that some contradictions are true, but in order to avoid triviality it is not explosive. Systems of logic that include the principle of explosion do not allow contradictions on pain of collapsing into triviality. The principle of explosion does not generate contradictions, it states what would follow if there were any.

Comment: @Bumble This is fascinating but you clearly totally fail to understand my answer. This is typical of people coming from mathematical logic. I always answer questions about logic on the reasonable assumption that logic is the logic of human deductive reasoning and nothing else. People trained in mathematical logic like you always interpret my answers through the semantics of mathematical logic and so you all systematically misunderstand what I say. I don't think I have to explain anything. You won't be interested and, beside, it is already explained in my answer.

Comment: I have little or no interest in mathematical logic. My interest in logic is entirely philosophical and I am not a mathematician. I do understand your answer and it is simply incorrect.

Comment: @Bumble The question appeared to be about formal logic. Dialethism is not formal logic. It has a different range of application and different methods and precepts.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Be careful that you do not mix up different meanings of "logical." There is the meaning of "be logical" meaning use rational thought and think carefully and remove logic errors. There is also "logical system" meaning a collection of abstract objects and rules that allow the construction of theorems. It is certainly possible for a logical system to contain contradiction (meaning it is not self consistent) but to still be logical (meaning it was carefully and correctly constructed).

Comment: @BillOnne There are dialethic logics, such as the Logic of Paradox (LP), which are formal logics. They can be axiomatized and represented in conventional ways using axioms and rules of inference. They can also be expressed using truth tables and tableaux in a similar way to other logics. They have different applications, to be sure, but that doesn't make them something other than formal logics. I also understood the question to be about formal systems of logic.

Comment: @BillOnne 1. "*correctly constructed*" Sure. I accept that mathematical logic systems are logical in the sense you suggests. I even assume that mathematical logic systems are derived logically from fundamental assumptions. I don't have the time and patience to verify this but I have no good reason to think it wrong. 2. The question is about "*logic* systems", which I take to mean formal systems meant to model logic. Self-contradictory systems may well be derived logically from assumption but they are not logical systems in the sense relevant here that they cannot model logic.